# Как распарсить json с помощью gson?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

С сервера получаю такой Json:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","properties":{"Attribution":{"Sources":{"yandex":{"id":"yandex","author":{"name":"Яндекс","uri":"https:\/\/www.yandex.ru"}}}},"ResponseMetaData":{"SearchRequest":{"request":"Веломастерская,ремонт велосипедов","results":1,"skip":0,"boundedBy":[[37.048426749999997,55.436448290000001],[38.175902260000001,56.046901239999997]]},"SearchResponse":{"found":80,"Point":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[23.820850969999999,53.669822070000002]},"boundedBy":[[23.81916214,53.668824499999999],[23.822539800000001,53.670819620000003]],"display":"multiple"}}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":"1","CompanyMetaData":{"id":"1153226678","name":"Веломастерская","nameHighlight":[[0,14]],"address":"Гродно, ул. Советских Пограничников, 51\/1","Categories":[{"name":"Ремонт велосипедов"}],"Phones":[{"type":"phone","formatted":"+375 (29) 785-43-26","country":"375","prefix":"29","number":"7854326"}],"Hours":{"Availabilities":[{"Monday":true,"Tuesday":true,"Wednesday":true,"Thursday":true,"Friday":true,"Intervals":[{"from":"17:00:00","to":"20:00:00"}]}],"text":"пн-пт 17:00–20:00","tzOffset":10800},"Geo":{"precision":"exact"}},"description":"Гродно, ул. Советских Пограничников, 51\/1","name":"Веломастерская","boundedBy":[[23.812622399999999,53.66493534],[23.829079539999999,53.67470823]],"attributions":["#yandex"]},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[23.820847000000001,53.669820000000001]},"geometries":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[23.820847000000001,53.669820000000001]}]}]}
```

Меня интересуют поля Name, address и formatted.

Как  мне его распарсить с помощью gson?

P.S Можно пример кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так. Идея, я думаю, ясна.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String jsonString = "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"properties\":{\"Attribution\":{\"Sources\":{\"yandex\":{\"id\":\"yandex\",\"author\":{\"name\":\"Яндекс\",\"uri\":\"https:\\/\\/www.yandex.ru\"}}}},\"ResponseMetaData\":{\"SearchRequest\":{\"request\":\"Веломастерская,ремонт велосипедов\",\"results\":1,\"skip\":0,\"boundedBy\":[[37.048426749999997,55.436448290000001],[38.175902260000001,56.046901239999997]]},\"SearchResponse\":{\"found\":80,\"Point\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[23.820850969999999,53.669822070000002]},\"boundedBy\":[[23.81916214,53.668824499999999],[23.822539800000001,53.670819620000003]],\"display\":\"multiple\"}}},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"CompanyMetaData\":{\"id\":\"1153226678\",\"name\":\"Веломастерская\",\"nameHighlight\":[[0,14]],\"address\":\"Гродно, ул. Советских Пограничников, 51\\/1\",\"Categories\":[{\"name\":\"Ремонт велосипедов\"}],\"Phones\":[{\"type\":\"phone\",\"formatted\":\"+375 (29) 785-43-26\",\"country\":\"375\",\"prefix\":\"29\",\"number\":\"7854326\"}],\"Hours\":{\"Availabilities\":[{\"Monday\":true,\"Tuesday\":true,\"Wednesday\":true,\"Thursday\":true,\"Friday\":true,\"Intervals\":[{\"from\":\"17:00:00\",\"to\":\"20:00:00\"}]}],\"text\":\"пн-пт 17:00–20:00\",\"tzOffset\":10800},\"Geo\":{\"precision\":\"exact\"}},\"description\":\"Гродно, ул. Советских Пограничников, 51\\/1\",\"name\":\"Веломастерская\",\"boundedBy\":[[23.812622399999999,53.66493534],[23.829079539999999,53.67470823]],\"attributions\":[\"#yandex\"]},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[23.820847000000001,53.669820000000001]},\"geometries\":[{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[23.820847000000001,53.669820000000001]}]}]}";

        final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        final JsonObject root = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

        final String name = root.getAsJsonObject("properties")
                                .getAsJsonObject("Attribution")
                                .getAsJsonObject("Sources")
                                .getAsJsonObject("yandex")
                                .getAsJsonObject("author")
                                .get("name").toString();
        System.out.println("name = " + name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

О парсинге JSON вообще и на Андроиде в часности.

1. Если структура JSON известна заранее и надо вытянуть из нее всего пару значений, зачем его вообще парсить? Воспользуйтесь поиском по строке и найдите что надо. Человек ведь в мозгу не парсит JSON, а ищет ключевые слова и вытаскивает значения. Напишите код точно так же как думаете сами.
2. Если все-таки лучше парсить, но маппить никуда не надо, посмотрите на стандартный `org.json.JSONObject`, он прекрасно работает с небольшими обьемами, никаких внешних зависимостей.
3. И только после обдумывания пп.1 и 2, можно начать выбирать между `GSON` и `Jackson`. При больших обьемах парсить потоки, не строки.

Answer (score 2):

Есть удобный сайт http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ если вставить в него исходный JSON на выходе получаем набор классов:

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Attribution {

    @SerializedName("Sources")
    @Expose
    private Sources sources;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The sources
     */
    public Sources getSources() {
        return sources;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param sources
     * The Sources
     */
    public void setSources(Sources sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
    }

}
```

сам JSON обрабатываем например примерно так:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Attribution attributionObj = gson.fromJson(gsonString, Attribution.class);
```